# Process to change userId i.e. mobile number to another one

Tags: android, database, algorithm, design-patterns, architecture

I am designing application's functional and structural flow and need suggestion in one condition. 
In this application mobile number is a userId of a user i.e. user can register to the app through mobile number and now he/she wants to change the mobile number and want all the data on the current number. So what should be the process to do all this ?? 
Your suggestion will add value to my thought. Thanks..

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use a phone number or other user data as ID when it is possible to change it. Applications will use an ID to identify a specific user, when this ID changes, they will not be able to find that user again.

Comment: Yes, identifiers should be stable. Besides, the question seems too broad  - "what should the process be ?"... in terms of what ?

Comment: like whatsapp, it gives an option to change number in Settings-> Accounts-> Change Number and ask user to enter old and new mobile number, then it send an OTP to new mobile number and after entering that otp, it changed the old number to new one and all the groups or chats of old number are now with the new number. So it is the process and I need more options likewise ..

Comment: Please check the above comment @guillaume31

Comment: I'm pretty sure Whatsapp has another unique user identifier than the phone number. Plus, it's still unclear what you are really looking for... Do you have a precise question to ask?

Comment: @Araju User can register with phoneNum is no problem. But you don't need to mix the things up and make that (phoneNum) the primary key (identifier) of your user info database. Instead you should use another unique identifier which is hidden from the users as guillaume31 suggested. :)